# Calculating distance beetween longitude latitude pairs in Arcmap or Qgis

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, qgis, arcmap

How can i calculate `DISTANCE` column between each rows (around 100) in attribute table of Arcmap or Qgis?

Here is the header row:

`name lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2 DISTANCE(empty)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to store "around 100"-1 distances in that single column?

Comment: And distances from which points? You have two sets of coordinates in each row.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to calculate the distance between lon1-lat1 and lon2-lat2 for each row?
See this post:
[How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)